# how to get ip address using rack and geocoder

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack, rails-geocoder

I want to get the location of an IP address with geocoder. The [docs](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#request-geocoding-by-ip-address) say to use the following line:

```
result = request.location
```

But that gives a NameError and says "request" is undefined. So I figured I needed a Rack::Request object:

```
result = Rack::Request.new(env)
```

But that toos gives a NameError - this time saying that `env` is undefined.

So I checked for `env` in a new script with the following:

```
require "rack" 
def pp(hash)
 hash.map {|key,value| "#{key} => #{value}"}.sort.join("<br/>") 
end
Rack::Handler::WEBrick.run lambda {|env| [200,{},[pp(env)]]} , :Port=>3000
```

When I run that and go to localhost:3000 I see the env hash. Is `env` not set by default in Rack?

I cannot figure this out, and I know it's because I'm missing something.

Comment: This will probably be easier if you post the code that isn't working.

Comment: @FrederickCheung `city = request.location.city` gives a "method is not defined" NameError, so it made sense to create an object on which i could apply request with `result = Rack::Request.new(env)`. This results in another name error, but this time for `env`

Comment: op edited for clarity

Comment: When I say post the code I mean (ideally) a complete, runnable example - not fragments from various attempts.

Comment: I would, but my entire issue is that I cannot get past the first step, and thus cannot build anything. The geocoder docs say that `city = request.location.city` should be sufficient for getting visitor IP in a Rack-based framework, but my experience so far with that approach has been nothing but NameErrors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Fixing your Geocoder setup

The code you're following from the docs assumes you will be hosting the snippet from "within a rails controller or Sinatra app."  To get it working with Sinatra is fairly straightforward.  Populate the following two files from your project directory:

```
# Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'sinatra'
gem 'geocoder'

#######################

# main.rb
require 'sinatra'
require 'geocoder'

get '/' do
  <<-HTMLOUT
  <html>
  <body>
  <p><strong>Request Location</strong>: #{request.location.inspect}</p>
  </body>
  </html>
HTMLOUT
end
```

Then from your terminal run `bundle install` and start up the app `ruby main.rb -p 4567`.  Go to http://localhost:4567 to check.  Because it's localhost, none of the geocode data will be populated... but that should get you started.

---

#### Regarding the undefined error

You should be able to find Rack's environment variable within `ENV['RACK_ENV']`.  Try adding this snippet to your code:

```
env = ENV["RACK_ENV"] || "development"
```

---

#### Ruby shorthand default assignment

This Ruby shorthand assignment technique is useful for assigning a default value if our config has not been set.  For example:

```
# pretend FAKE_ENV is your ENV  
FAKE_ENV = {"DEFINED_KEY" => "defined_value"}
env = FAKE_ENV["DEFINED_KEY"] || "my_default"
# => "defined_value
env = FAKE_ENV["UNDEFINED_KEY"] || "my_default"
# => "my_default"
```

Comment: This sets env to either nil or "development". Not what I'm looking for.

Comment: It ensures that `env` is set to either your `env["RACK_ENV"]` or a default ("development") so that it **can't** be `nil`, which was the error you reported.  Please see my edit for how Ruby shorthand default assignment works.

Comment: I am a very stupid person. "within a rails controller or Sinatra app" - that.

Comment: And additionally - the call to `request.location` must be made within a route. Therein lied my problem. Good lord. T_T Thanks!